# Is it correct to use "is able" in this context?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

This is the first time my manager let me send an email to a partner company.

I wrote this:

> The current version of the Windows application **is able** to: 
>     1. Create a new CSV file according to user inputs 
>     2. Validate integer values 
>     3. Validate values’ lengths according to the database design 
>     4. Search for already-saved CSV files using FarmID 
>     5. Update a CSV file 
>     The current version of the synchronization tool **is able** to: 
>     1. Read a large number of CSV files 
>     2. Update the database

Is it correct to use “is able” in this context?

Comment: Sorry, proofreading is offtopic here. But since this is the *first time dealing,* I'd give you my opinion. The content is fine to send! :) However, I'd not use colons there and probably put three dots as we are keeping the sentence incomplete. Therefore, the first letter of all bullet points won't be capital as well. But that's what I think! All the best.

Comment: He's not asking for proofreading, his question is just about the usage of one single form: is able.

Comment: Actually the colon is the only way to go when a list such as this follows. An ellipsis would look unprofessional and awkward.

Comment: @MaulikV it is not proofreading. I asked about the `is able`, which is an english question. please re open the question. there are other users who see that this question is not proofreading like `CocoPop`

Comment: @CocoPop yes thank you. i don't know why the quetiosn is considered as proofreading. i need to know if `is able` is correct. anyway, i waited for like 30 minutes and no one answered me so I sent the email as it is and my manager didn't say anything bad to me :) :)

Comment: @CocoPop do you read the line *"...please if there is any other mistake tell me because this..."?* Had it been only asking about whether or not *is able..* possible, I wouldn't have voted it.

Comment: @MaulikV: I ignored that line because the title poses an interesting and valid question. As you can see, I didn't proofread it (although the rest is good too). Perhaps if OP would remove the last sentence from his post?

Comment: @CocoPop of course, I then withdraw my vote! :)

Comment: @MaulikV so you judged the whole question immediately because you saw that line? It like a soldier kills a boy because he has a game gun.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I did not judge that way. I have my opinion though. See the comment. If you have a thousand word question with even a half line *kindly proofread* it's sufficient. I answered in my comment for that valid portion of the question.

Comment: Edited and voted to reopen. I think now it's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"is able to" is perfectly fine here.

You can alternatively use "can" with the same meaning, which would be my personal choice.